What do you call this unusual type, style, or placement of staircase?
What do you call this type of architectural feature - an unusual staircase in the middle of a space surrounded by an open railing? There is suddenly a hole or hatch in the floor, surrounded by a railing, with a staircase that descends here into the basement? Theres no walls around the hatch or hole in the floor. It’s completely open. Never have I seen this before and it perplexes me, almost reminds me of a wooden pirate ship for some reason. Thanks for your feedback





You might have a better chance of finding an answer on Home Improvement SE.

If by 'pirate ship' you mean the classic 'Age of Sail' vessel - yes, access to the lower decks was typically central (as it is in modern ships, because the ship's sides are curved!).  I don't know that this is so unusual; it's found in large houses with rooms all round a central hall/landing.

I'd point out this is almost certainly a remodel of a quite old house - from well before air conditioning was common in the area.  It didn't look like that when it was built. Somebody wanted to  open it up and took down walls, including a load bearing wall that was replaced by beams and posts. The tray ceiling above the fan was probably home to an old exhaust ventilator hidden in dead space above the old stairwell partitions.

It's usually called and open stair or open stairwell - meaning without walls or partitions around the well. The same terms also are used to describe a staircase without risers. So it doesn't work great as a search term.
The treatment at the bottom is called a flare.
https://designedstairs.com/terminology.php

I have seen it called a split staircase. Often there’s a single flight up to a landing that then splits T-shapedly to a matched pair of landings at the top. But the house my wife grew up in had the split at the bottom. Coming down in the morning, you could turn left into the kitchen or right into the front room.
That T-landing and the opposing lower flights were on an exterior wall (with a window at the landing). This allowed for an exterior door at grade midway between the public (ground) floor and the cellar because the cellar stairs were stacked under the main single flight and then turned left (below the kitchen) at the side-door landing.
I hasten to point out that in that house, there were bedroom walls at either side of the single upper flight, so it didn’t have the crowning 3-sided balustrade as in your photos.
For a similar setup, check out this post on Reddit.
